# Wireless on dv1000 works while installing but not while using

Tags: installation, wireless

That's it. When I install ubuntu (and xubuntu) I can use the wireless of the HP dv1000 for download packages, but after the installation is ready and it comes to the real work..fail it is like I wouldnt have a wireless adaptor, there is not any connection or anything where I can see that I have a wireless device...what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same computer without dual boot and the WIFI works like a charm, no problem with it. I think that you have to install and activate the correct driver for the wifi (it should be the Broadcom driver, if I remember well), going to Additional drivers (you can search it through the Unity lens).